# why xcode console font is bigger than editor font

Tags: xcode, macos, fonts, font-size

I know the font size in xcode can be set in Preference -> Fonts & Colors. But, even I set **THE SAME** font size for editor area and console area, the two areas show text with visually different size. The size 15 in console area is a little bigger than size 15 in editor area, but it's smaller than size 15.1. Seems the two area shows text with completely different mechanism (or engine?).

I try several other editors & browsers that can show mono fonts, find that Terminal and Sublime Text2 shows the same size as xcode editor area, while Firefox and svnX review area shows the same size as xcode console area. My question is:

How to make the editor area show text with exactly the same size as the console area? I like the console area font size.

Answer (score 31):

Under Preferences > Fonts & Colors, you need to click the Console label (circled in the screenshot below).

[image: Xcode 5.1.1 screenshot]

I usually just select all the options listed and give them the same font size.